# Build notification system

Tags: apache-kafka

I was trying to build a notification system using Apache kafka and spring boot.

App details -
The app has two flows
1.User writes a review which is added to review table in db and the same is recorded in the notification table.
2.The user fetches the notification from the notification table.

Apache kafka flow-

1.We create a producer that pushes the message that notification is received to the kafka broker.
2. We create the consumer for each user and poll the broker for new notification.

So the follow up question is
1.Is the architecture correct?
2.How many producer would be idle and how many brokers. What is the scaling factor.
3.What would be the most optimal approach if the above is flaky.

Comment: At least for your task `We create a producer that pushes the message that notification is received to the kafka broker` you don't need this because for this `Kafka Connect` is designated. Just pick up a proper Kafka Connector for your database like for [MySQL](https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql) so your data in the *notification table* flow into a Kafka Topic.

Comment: Thanks @kladderradatsch, follow up to the above, what would be the rule of the thumb to determine no of kafka brokers and also rule of thumb to add consumers to particular group

Comment: I don't know this. Just begin with one broker and one consumer and you'll see.